# How to add data from data sheet to another sheet with macro button?

Tags: excel

I want to add data with a button from a data sheet to a bill sheet, but its not working. The code is working correctly when I'm running at bill sheet but doesn't work when I run it in the data sheet.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 22 To 42
If IsEmpty(Range("C" & i)) Then

Sheets("PRICE LIST").Range("C3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("INVOICE EU").Range("C" & i)
Sheets("PRICE LIST").Range("D3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("INVOICE EU").Range("E" & i)
Sheets("PRICE LIST").Range("E3").Copy Destination:=Sheets("INVOICE EU").Range("K" & i)
Sheets("INVOICE EU").Range("L" & i).Value = Sheets("PRICE LIST").Range("F3").Value

Exit For

Else
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

data sheet is PRICE LIST and bill sheet is INVOICE EU

Comment: The line `If IsEmpty(Range("C" & i)) Then` is dependant on the sheet you are working on as it does not specify Price List or Invoice EU. Is that by design?

Comment: I just check if cell is empty, because i have more than 300 records

Comment: I understand that but which cells are you checking. On either sheet or on one of the sheets specifically?

Comment: Thanks I found the wrong place and corrected it . Now is working fine.

Comment: Made an answer from my comment. Cant tell if it helped or not since you didnt specify what you fixed. If it did help please mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You mention that the macro has different effects on different sheets. The line defined below is dependent on the sheet with focus

```
If IsEmpty(Range("C" & i)) Then
```

Is it possible you want to refer to a particular sheet when checking range c22:c42?